# Show loading message/ image while sorting jquery datatable column

Tags: sorting, datatables

My datatable consist of very huge data and hence sorting takes quite longer duration. Is there any provision that I can show some loading image/ message while the sorting process is in progress on given column?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try [this](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html)

You can set the position according to the column and bind it with the click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#TABLE').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "ajax": {
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ACTION", "CONTROLLER")',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: function (d) {
      //DATA YOU PASS
    } 
  },
  "columnDefs": [{ "className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all" }],
  "columns": [
    {
      "className": 'details-control',
      "orderable": false,
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": '',
      width: '5px'
    },
    { "data": "status", "orderable": true, title: "Status" },
    { "data": "count", "orderable": true, title: "Project Count" }
  ],
  "order": [[1, 'asc']],
  "scrollCollapse": true,
  "paging": true,
  "bDestroy": true,
  "dom": "lftipr",
  "language": {
    "processing": ' <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw" style="color: #1E407C; font-size: 50px;"></i>',
  }
});
```