# Show loading when sorting vuetify v-data-table

Tags: sorting, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have a big v-data-table and when I click on the header to sort it it takes quite some time. Is there a way to show loading or at least get when it is done sorting ?

I found the event for when the sort is changed (`@update:sortBy="eventSortBy"`), but it is fired just at the beginning and I would need to know when the sorting is done.

I've looked on the v-data-table doc but can't find it.

Similar to [Show loading message/ image while sorting jquery datatable column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714458/show-loading-message-image-while-sorting-jquery-datatable-column) but for v-data-table

Thanks!

Example:

```
<template>
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    @update:sortBy="eventSortBy"
></v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
....
methods: {
    eventSortBy(x: any) {
        console.log(x)  // This fire only when we start sorting, I would need the event when it is done sorting
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you need to show a big data table, you should use [v-data-table-virtual](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#v-data-table-virtual). Sorting millions data is very fast, what really takes time is the `DOM reflow`.